# Assign value to anchor tag - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

User sees a list of options (eg: 1.Apple ; 2.Banana ; 3.Mango). There is a textbox where user types in the desired option and clicks send to proceed further.

**Existing Setup:**

**HTML:**

```
<p ng-repeat="opt in objHistory.OptionItems track by $index">
  {{ opt.SortOrder }}. {{ opt.OptionName }}
</p>
<textarea ng-model="userInput"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="GetNextItem()">Send</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.GetNextItem = function () {
  alert($scope.userInput);
  //some code
}
```

The above code is working good. But now I have changed the options to anchor tags, so user can click on them, instead of typing and the same flow follows.

**New HTML:**

```
<p ng-repeat="opt in objHistory.OptionItems track by $index">
  <a href="javascript:;" 
  ng-model = "userInput"
  ng-init="userInput=opt.SortOrder" 
  ng-click="GetNextItem()">{{ opt.SortOrder }}. {{ opt.OptionName }}
  </a>
</p>
```

I get `undefined` in the alert now. Where am I going wrong? Can the same `ng-model` variable name be used multiple times (I'm using it for the `textbox` and also the `anchor` tags)?

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are trying to read the set value before Angular is done assigning.

HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="opt in objHistory.OptionItems track by $index">
  <a href="javascript:;" 
  ng-model = "userInput"
  ng-init="init(opt)" 
  ng-click="GetNextItem()">{{ opt.SortOrder }}. {{ opt.OptionName }}
  </a>
</p>
<textarea ng-model="userInput"></textarea>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller("MainController", function($scope) {

  $scope.GetNextItem = function () {
  alert($scope.userInput);
  //some code
};

  $scope.init = function(opt) {
    $scope.userInput = opt.SortOrder; // set it in the init method
  };
  $scope.objHistory = {
    OptionItems: [{
      SortOrder : "1",
      OptionName: "Hi"

    }, {
      SortOrder : "2",
      OptionName: "Hi"

    }]
  }
});
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mafefonizo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Update based on comment:

```
 $scope.GetNextItem = function (opt) {
  $scope.userInput = opt.SortOrder;
  //some code
 };
```

Now in your HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="opt in objHistory.OptionItems track by $index">
  <a href="javascript:;" 
  ng-click="GetNextItem(opt)">{{ opt.SortOrder }}. {{ opt.OptionName }}
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: I would like to assign the clicked SortOrder to `userInput`. But in your case it will always be 2.

Comment: ok.I figured it out...have a new function inside which you assign value to `userInput`...`ng-click="TakeUserInput(opt.SortOrder)"`....`$scope.TakeUserInput= function(optionNumber) {
    $scope.userInput = optionNumber;
  };`

Comment: you need to have ng-init in text area in that case

Comment: The textbox value will not be in use when user clicks an option right. so that wouldnt work too. But thank you for the idea

Comment: Great. please accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

`ng-model` cannot be used on anchor tags unless you have an input field or a custom directive. According to docs:

> The `ngModel` directive binds an `input`,`select`, `textarea` (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using `NgModelController`, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Why are you using `ngModel` on anchor tags?

Sorry not enough rep to comment

Answer (score 0):

Move `ng-model` to the parent `<p>`